# Modify HTML within a Dom-repeat

Tags: javascript, polymer, repeat

I'm stuck on a basic thing, but which gets very complex with Polymer. I would like to change the text color of a table cell according to the value in it. I've tried using `filter` in `dom-repeat`, but it doesn't work because I don't know how to access HTML this way.

Here's sample code:

```
    <h4>[[propertiesList.length]] Properties available</h4>
    <paper-card elevation="1">
        <div class="tableRow title">
            <div class="title colM">Name</div>
            <div class="title colL">URL</div>
            <div class="title colM">Owned by</div>
            <div class="title colS">Created</div>
            <div class="title colM">Videos count</div>
            <div class="title colM">Status</div>
            <div class="title colXS">Edit</div>
        </div>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[propertiesList]]" filter="StatusColor">
            <div class="tableRow">
                <div class="colM">[[item.name]]</div>
                <div class="colL">[[item.url]]</div>
                <div class="colM">[[item.user.name]]</div>
                <div class="colS">[[item.created]]</div>
                <div class="colM">[[item.videos_count]]</div>
                <div class="colM" id="status">[[item.status.label]]</div>
                <div class="colXS left"><paper-icon-button class="editIcon" on-tap="editProperty" icon="mdi:pencil"></paper-icon-button></div>
            </div>                
        </template>
    </paper-card>
```

and the JS:

```
        StatusColor: function (item) {
            if (item.status.label == "Active") {
                document.getElementById("status").style.color = '#48C8B6';
                console.log("Property is active");
                return item.status.label;
            }
        },
```

...doesn't do anything to my text color.

Then, I've tried a good old `for`-loop, but for some reason, I can't get the `.length` value right. Here's the same HTML as above minus the `filter`, and `"status"` is now a `class` instead of `id`. The JS is as follows:

```
        attached: function () {
            this.async(function () {
                var status = document.getElementsByClassName("status");
                console.log("Status value : ", status);
                var count = status.length;
                console.log("count value : ", count);
                for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    var text = status[i].innerText;
                    if (text == "Active") {
                        status[i].style.color = "#48C8B6";
                    } else {
                        status[i].style.color = "#F1412E";
                    }
                }
            });
```

My first `console.log` that shows the `status` value is right. I get all my "status" `div`s, and the `length` property in Chrome Dev Tools is the right one, but the second `console.log` (the "count" one) always displays `0`. Thus, I can't make my `for`-loop work properly.

Help me (...obiwan kenobi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the template [`filter`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates#filtering-and-sorting-lists) is intended for filtering out items from your repeater (not for mapping items as you attempted to do). Also, the template repeater invokes the `filter` callback *before* stamping an item. On the first iteration, the `#status` node will not have been stamped yet, so `document.getElementById('status')` would return `null` (assuming no other node with ID of `status` exists already), resulting in a `TypeError` and nothing rendered for that template repeater.

Instead of the template filter or the `attached` callback, I recommend the following:

- CSS styles for default and active statuses (keep behavioral logic in JS, and styles in CSS)
- Conditionally assigned `class` for status `div` (using a [computed binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#annotated-computed) with [attribute binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#native-binding))

As in:

```
// style
.status {
  color: #F1412E;
}
.status.active {
  color: #48C8B6;
}

// template ($= for native attribute binding)
<div class$="[[_computeStatusStyle(item.status.label)]]">[[item.status.label]]</div>

// script
Polymer({
  _computeStatusStyle: function(label) {
    var baseStyle = "colM status";
    var activeStyle = label === "Active" ? " active" : "";
    return baseStyle + activeStyle;
  }
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.5.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="paper-card/paper-card.html">
</head>

<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <style>
      paper-card {
        width: 100%;
      }
      .tableRow {
        margin: 1rem;
        border-bottom: solid 1px lightgray;
      }
      .status {
        color: #F1412E;
      }
      .status.active {
        color: #48C8B6;
      }
    </style>

    <template>
      <h4>[[propertiesList.length]] Properties available</h4>
      <paper-card elevation="1">
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[propertiesList]]">
          <div class="tableRow">
            <div class="colM">[[item.name]]</div>
            <div class="colL">[[item.url]]</div>
            <div class="colM">[[item.user.name]]</div>
            <div class="colS">[[item.created]]</div>
            <div class="colM">[[item.videos_count]]</div>
            <div class$="[[_computeStatusStyle(item.status.label)]]">[[item.status.label]]</div>
            <div class="colXS left">
              <paper-icon-button class="editIcon" on-tap="editProperty" icon="mdi:pencil"></paper-icon-button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </template>
      </paper-card>
    </template>
    <script>
      HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
        "use strict";

        Polymer({
          is: 'x-foo',
          properties: {
            propertiesList: {
              type: Array,
              value: generateProperties
            }
          },
          _computeStatusStyle: function(label) {
            var baseStyle = "colM status";
            var activeStyle = label === "Active" ? " active" : "";
            return baseStyle + activeStyle;
          }
        });

        /** Value generator for <x-foo>.propertiesList above */
        function generateProperties() {
          var props = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            var statusLabel = i % 2 == 0 ? 'Active' : 'Inactive';
            props.push(new Property('name', 'url', 'username', 'created', 'videoCount', statusLabel));
          }
          return props;
        }

        /** Property class for <x-foo>.propertiesList above */
        function Property(name, url, username, created, videoCount, label) {
          this.name = name;
          this.url = url;
          this.user = {};
          this.user.name = username;
          this.created = created;
          this.videos_count = videoCount;
          this.status = {};
          this.status.label = label;
        };

      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/EyNMeg?editors=1000)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks (again) Tony19! Btw, can you remind me what the `$` in ` <div class$="[[_computeStatusStyle(item.status.label)]]">` stands for?

Comment: No problem :-) I've updated the answer with link to native attribute binding, which explains `$=`.